# Can I edit multiple sites with an online Wordpress account?

Tags: plugins, multisite

I have a site built using the browser version of Wordpress.  I'd like to build and manage another website but use the same Wordpress account.

For example, I'd like to manage the domains and edit the pages for [www.websiteA.com](http://www.websiteA.com)  and [www.websiteB.com](http://www.websiteB.com).

Sorry if this is a naive question.  I can always make another Wordpress account but I'd like to avoid managing multiple accounts for each page I build.

Would I need to install the Wordpress software on my computer and manage the websites from my own server?

Comment: Have you looked into multisite installations of WordPress?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, Justin.Seems like you are asking about managing sites in WordPress.com (the service provided by Automattic) am I right? If so, questions regarding it are considered off-topic here, as [explained here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the best place to get help would be [their support](https://wordpress.com/support/) page.